# Different editor for collection and maintitle

Tags: biblatex, biber

BibLaTeX/biber seems to be unable to handle the following case: A `@Collection` is part of another series-like collection (`series` has already been used), for which I use `maintitle` (`series` has already been used). But: The `@Collection`'s `editor` is not the `maintitle`'s editor ...

To give an example *how it should look like*

```
@BookInBook{Erler:PlatonHaBu,
  title =    {Platon},
  year =     2007,
  author =   {Michael Erler},
  gender =   {sm},
  booktitle ={Die Philosophie der Antike},
  editor =   {Hellmut Flashar},
  maintitle ={Grundriss der Geschichte der Philosophie},
  language = {german},
  volume =   2,
  part =     2,
  publisher = {Schwabe},
  location = {Basel}
}
```

becomes (using BibLaTeX/biber with `style=philosophy-modern`, which shouldn't make any difference)

> Erler, Michael
>
> 2007 *Platon*, in *Grundriss der Geschichte der Philosophie*, Bd. 2.2:
>   *Die Philosophie der Antike*, hrsg. von Hellmut Flashar, Basel: Schwabe.
>
> Excellent: 20 volumes *Outlines of the History of Philosophy*
>   (`maintitle`) --> part of it: *Ancient Philosophy* (`booktitle`,
>   `editor` is Flashar) --> single volume: *Plato* (`title`, `author` ist
>   Erler)

**BUT**:

```
@Collection{JongNuenlist:Time,
  editor =   {Irene J. F. de Jong AND Ren{\'e} N{\"u}nlist},
  sortname = {Jong, Irene J. F. de AND Rene{\'e} N{\"u}nlist},
  gender =   {pp},
  title =    {Time in Ancient Greek Literature},
  booktitle = {Time in Ancient Greek Literature},
  shorttitle = {Time},
  maintitle = {Studies in Ancient Greek Narrative},
  volume =   2,
  language = {english},
  year =     2007,
  series =   {Mnemosyne. Supplementum},
  number =   291,
  publisher = {Brill},
  location = {Leiden AND Boston}
}
```

becomes

> De Jong, Irene J. F. und René Nünlist
>
> 2007a Hrsg., *Studies in Ancient Greek Narrative*, Bd. 2: *Time in
>   Ancient Greek Literature*, Mnemosyne. Supplementum 291, Leiden und
>   Boston: Brill.

I need it as `@Collection`, because I cite several `@InCollection`s. Neither are de Jong and Nünlist the editors of the `maintitle`, whereof there is no `editor` at all, but of this `@Collection`, nor do I want to print the `maintitle` before the `title` of the `@Collection`.

It should look like

> De Jong, Irene J. F. und René Nünlist
>
> 2007a Hrsg., *Time in Ancient Greek Literature*, in *Studies in
>   Ancient Greek Narrative*, Bd. 2, Mnemosyne. Supplementum 291, Leiden
>   und Boston: Brill.

The latter I get with `booktitleaddon`, which is un-TeXy, messy and unordered.

Answer (score 2):

I see that there is a problem for you to which BibLaTeX currently does not provide a solution. Yet, I think that this problem can be avoided, for to my mind your bib-entries do not faithfully represent the publications.

Erler is the author of a book "Plato". This book appeared in a series called "Grundriss der Geschichte der Philosophie". This series is so voluminous that it is subdivided in sections. So the book in question appeared in the subdivision "Die Philosophie der Antike" of which it is volume two, part two.

Series often have subdivisions. I handle them as subtitles of series using `\subtitlepunct`: `series = {Title of the Series\subtitlepunct Subtitle of the Series}`. IMHO, editors of a series need not (ought not?) be part of bibliographical reference.

My entry for Erler's book would look like this:

```
@Book{erler:uberweg:platon,
  author =   {Michael Erler},
  title =    {Platon},
  year =     {2007},
  series =   {Grundriss der Geschichte der Philosophie\subtitlepunct Die Philosophie der Antike},
  volume =   {2},
  part =     {2},
  publisher = {Schwabe Verlag},
  location = {Basel},
  language = {german}
}
```

I have to admit that Erler's book is a special case. Usually the volumes of the "Grundriss der Geschichte der Philosophie" series are *edited* books and thus usually have editors. Erler's book, however, is *authored* by Erler, and thus -- strictly speaking -- does not have an editor (apart from the general editor of the series, who -- as I said above -- should not be part of the reference).

To your other, more important, example: Here again, I think your entry distorts reality quite a bit. First of all, "Studies in Ancient Greek literature" did not appeare *in* a collection called "Studies in Ancient Greek Narrative" as your example suggests by using the preposition *in* after the title. Rather it is part of that series.

As I understand it, de Jong and Nünlist are editors of a collection called "Time in Ancient Greek Literature" which is a part of a series called "Mnemosyne supplementa". This series' 291st item is the book in question which in turn was published as part of a subseries called "Studies in Ancient Greek Narrative" which up to now has three numbers, yours is the second.

```
@collection{dejong:nunlist:time,
  editor =   {{Irene J. F.} de Jong and René Nünlist},
  title =    {Time in Ancient Greek Literature},
  year =     {2007},
  series =   {Mnemosyne supplementa 291\subtitlepunct Studies in Ancient Greek Narrative},
  number =   {2},
  publisher = {Brill},
  location = {Leiden and Boston},
  language = {english}
}
```

If you do this, your references will be correct and your problem does not appear at all.

The only drawback is in using `\subtitlepunct` which sort of renders the `number=` field weird (why is 291 in the `series`-field but 2 is not?).

(Btw you could also use `:`instead of `\subtitlepunct`)